# Find the missing term!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, knowledge, number-sequence

Complete the sequence and state the pattern/logic behind the answer.

> 8,9,10,11,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,?,48,72

The sequence ends at 72.

Comment: Does the ? indicate a single missing term, or could it be more than one?

Comment: @Randal'Thor a single missing term.

Comment: i think something to do with factors of 8 and 9 and last is 72 as 8*9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> 36

Because

> The numbers given are the default font sizes selectable in tools like Microsoft Word.

Comment: This was really impressive :)